# chef user action logging

Tags: chef, knife

I am using **chef** for managing all our cookbooks.

The problem is not only me who uses chef, I wonder if whether there is a way to logging all actions that uses completes.

In particular, I am interested when and who did `knife cookbook upload` and all other commands of `knife`.

If there is a way to log all users actions like `knife cookbook upload`

Answer (score 1):

Every action is logged in /var/log/chef/server.log. You can start by examining the file and exporting relevant information.

You can also try [santoku](https://github.com/knuckolls/knife-santoku) that supports event hooks on knife events and forward these events on a variety of services (hipchat, logstash etc).